# How to share variables between functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a number of different Javascript functions in my app that are sharing the same variables and functionality. How can these be simplified? Do I *have* to create a class that my functions inherit from or is there a simpler or better alternative?

```
function CreditCard() {

  const tag = document.querySelector('meta[name=stripe-publishable-key]');

  if (!tag) {
    return;
  }

  const key = tag.getAttribute('content');
  const stripe = Stripe(key);

  const form = document.querySelector('#credit_card_form');

  if (!form) {
    return;
  }

  const name = document.querySelector('#name');
  const email = document.querySelector('#email');

  const spinner = document.querySelector('#spinner');

  const fontName = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-name');
  const fontColor = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-color');
  const fontSource = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-source');
  const locale = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang');

  const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#stripe_error_message');
  const clientSecret = document.querySelector('#client_secret');
  const submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

  const elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [{
      family: fontName,
      src: fontSource
    }],
    locale: locale
  });

  const style = {
    base: {
      fontFamily: fontName,
      color: fontColor
    }
  };

  ...

}
```

---

```
function DirectDebit() {

  const tag = document.querySelector('meta[name=stripe-publishable-key]');

  if (!tag) {
    return;
  }

  const key = tag.getAttribute('content');
  const stripe = Stripe(key);

  const form = document.querySelector('#direct_debit_form');

  if (!form) {
    return;
  }

  const name = document.querySelector('#name');
  const email = document.querySelector('#email');

  const spinner = document.querySelector('#spinner');

  const fontName = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-name');
  const fontColor = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-color');
  const fontSource = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-font-source');
  const country = document.querySelector('#server_side_constants').getAttribute('data-country');
  const locale = document.querySelector('html').getAttribute('lang');

  const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#stripe_error_message');
  const clientSecret = document.querySelector('#client_secret');
  const submitButton = document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');

  const elements = stripe.elements({
    fonts: [{
      family: fontName,
      src: fontSource
    }],
    locale: locale
  });

  const style = {
    base: {
      fontFamily: fontName,
      color: fontColor
    }
  };

  ...

}
```

Comment: do you want to use `typescript`? Or just javascript?

Comment: Declare the shared vars outside your function scope.

Comment: All the const coming from something with an ID don't need to be in a function. Also cache the element so you only need to get it once: `const ssconsts = document.getElementById('#server_side_constants').dataset; fontName=ssconsts["font-name"]`

Comment: for sure there is a lot of room for re-usability, you can break function in smaller re-usable function which have codebase same for both type of cards, or you can re-define your function like function `handleCard(type){}` and based on type change selectors and other logic .

Comment: Why don't you declare the variables such as `tag` outside your functions?